# Not able to access api URL in Prestashop - 404 error

Tags: mod-rewrite, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am very disappointed as I am not able to access my Webservice in my site that is running with Prestashop 1.6 version. Due to this I am not able to connect with one of the major Prestashop ship module.
In short when I access https://example.com/api it is redirecting to 404 page.

Can anyone help me to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I spend 2 hours on this problem and I solved it by htaccess on the root directory.

I saw that line alone : 
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

I just add this before :
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoururl.com$

Now it works

Answer (score 1):

Interesting... The answer could be in your HTTP server's configuration...

By the way:
does your .htaccess file which is generated by PrestaShop and is located in your PrestaShop root folder have these lines:

RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

?

Comment: Yes these lines are there in the .htaccess file. The thing is that I am not able to directly access any for the files that are with .php extension.

Answer (score 0):

- Check CGI Mode option in webservices configuration.
- Activate DEBUG MODE in Prestashop. Some detailed errors may appear.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To use PrestaShop api following things should be done:

1. Enable PrestaShop webservice : Go to Advance Parameters  > Webservice and enable PrestaShop web service.
2. Add a key: After enabling the webservice add a key and select the resource which you want and give the desired permission to that resource.

The endpoint to your store's webservice is located in the /api/ folder at the root of your installation of Prestashop:

- If PrestaShop is installed at the root of your server, you can access
  the API here: http://example.com/api/
- If PrestaShop is installed in a subfolder of your server, you can
  access the API here: http://example.com/prestashop/api/

To access it, you need to provide your API key when request. There is no password, providing your API key is enough – and therefore the key should be kept secret by the user!

You can either type the API endpoint address directly then enter your API key, or indicate your API key in the address. Here is an example, with "UCCLLQ9N2ARSHWCXLT74KUKSSK34BFKX" being the API key.

- At the root of the server:
  http://UCCLLQ9N2ARSHWCXLT74KUKSSK34BFKX@example.com/api/
- In a subfolder of the server:
  http://UCCLLQ9N2ARSHWCXLT74KUKSSK34BFKX@example.com/prestasshop/api/

For more help you can view the prestashop webservice documentation.

Comment: This is enabled in my server. The thing is that I am not able access even a plain php file with just echo script placed in my server. It is redirecting to 404. like http://example.com/testing.php leads to 404 in my Prestashop site